Everything Appears Black in Render Mode And Material Preview, and it Lags My PC

It's the current version.
It has light sources, no matter what.
I did not modify any preferences.

In Previous Versions of Blender I had, it worked perfectly fine, but it doesn't in the 4.2 (or 4.1, I haven't tried that one yet).

This is what it looks like in Solid Mode, no issues.

This is what it looks like in Material Preview (and Render Mode), it's all pitch black, no matter what I do, I just downloaded the new version, and it is still like this.

Check that your graphics drivers are up to date. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/gpu/index.html#graphics-hardware.
